# trouble with deleting a record with laravel delete function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

I have a problem with laravel and deleting.
Basically this should delete a row from database but when i click on delete it redirects me back but it doesn't delete what it should
Here is the code im working on

```
            <div class="list-group">
                @forelse($categories as $category) 

                <h4>{{$category->name}}</h4>

                <form action="{{route('categories.destroy', $category->id)}}" method="POST" class="inline-it">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                    <input class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>

                <hr>

                @empty
                    <h5> - No categories.</h5>
                @endforelse
            </div>
```

route:

```
Route::resource('/categories','CategoriesController');
```

controller:

```
public function destroy(Categories $categories)
{
    $categories->delete();
    return back();
}
```

edit dd https://pastebin.com/s41djcUH

[edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu60e.png)

Comment: Are you are using soft delete?

Comment: No, i'm not using soft delete.

Comment: Print $categories in the controller action and see if you are getting Category object. Please add the output here once you print it.

Comment: Please add the output here once you print it:
dd($categories); in destroy action.

Comment: The code seems perfect. Print $categories->id and see if that id is there in db.

Comment: when i print the id it returns NULL

Comment: ok, so that's the issue. It's not able to find the model that is why it is not deleting anything.

Comment: why is that happening ? how can i fix it ?

Comment: In view, inside forelse loop. print dd($category->id)

Comment: it prints them correctly

Comment: What is your model name category or categories?

Comment: the name is Categories

Comment: fire, php artisan route:list command in console and show me the delete route for categories (all information URI, method etc)

Comment: Most probably the issue is with route model binding so it is no able to find the model and eventually not deleting anything

Comment: i posted the image but i think that the routes are correct since its displaying the name correctly

Comment: What name? Name of category?

Comment: route names look at the image on the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change $categories with $category

```
public function destroy(Categories $category)
{
    $category->delete();
    return back();
}
```

For Implicit Route Model Binding: 
https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding

Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names **match** a route segment name.

Comment: A pleasure to help.